# recording sound in ruby, windows

Tags: ruby, audio, record, microphone

I wonder how can I record sound from microphone in ruby, windows xp or 7

for detecting pitch

google "ruby record audio", "ruby sound recording"

doesn't give me any answers

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but there's a ruby-PortAudio wrapper available [here](https://github.com/jvoorhis/ruby-portaudio).

Here's the site for the [PortAudio API](http://www.portaudio.com/).

Hope that helps!